# "detail": "Method \"GET\" not allowed. on calling endpoint in django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I'm using django.rest_framework. I have a get_or_create method for a particular view,

```
class LocationView(views.APIView):
    def get_or_create(self, request):
        try:
            location = Location.objects.get(country=request.data.get("country"), city=request.data.get("city"))
            Response(location, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        except Location.DoesNotExist:
            serializer = LocationSerializer(data=request.data)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                serializer.save()
                return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
            else:
                Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

This is the location Model,

```
class Location(models.Model):
    country = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    latitude = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    longitude = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('country', 'city')
```

This is my url,

```
url(r'^location/$', LocationView.as_view(), name='location'),
```

When I call this endpoint in the following way,
 http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/bouncer/location/?country=USA&&city=Sunnyvale&&latitude=122.0363&&longitude=37.3688

This is what I get,

```
{
    "detail": "Method \"GET\" not allowed."
}
```

What am I missing here.

Comment: change `get_or_create()` to `get()`

Comment: But I need get_or_create, it has a different purpose.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49181262/django-rest-api-get-and-post-request-in-one-go-post-request-based-on-the-get

Comment: I have faced this error because of double slashes in url (caused by postman environment variables). e.g. `api.example.com/v1//accounts` can also result in this error. Easily fixed by removing the additional slash

Answer (score 9):

The `Method not allowed` error is because, it searches for a `get()` method inside your API class, and it couldn't find a one.
The general format of the API class is as below

```
class LocationView(views.APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        #do something with 'GET' method
        return Response("some data")

    def post(self, request):
        #do something with 'POST' method
        return Response("some data")
```

If you want to invoke the `get_or_create()` method at some point, you can do it as any other methods,

```
class LocationView(views.APIView):
    def get_or_create(self, request):
        # do some "get or create" stuff
        return "some data"

    def get(self, request):
        if condition:
            self.get_or_create(request)
            # do some stuff
            return Response(" some special data related to get or create")
        return Response("some data")
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide separate methods for `get` and `post`. If your `get` method also creates an instance, then you can just call your current `get_or_create` inside both `get` and `post` methods.

```
class LocationView(views.APIView):

    def get_or_create(self, request):
        # your current definition here

    def get(self, request):
       return self.get_or_create(request)

    def post(self, request):
       return self.get_or_create(request)
```

Comment: Couldn you provide a little code example from my existing code. That will help understanding.

Comment: I'd also suggest you take a look at the default `Manager.get_or_create` Django provides, so you don't have to do the logic yourself inside the `try except` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create

Answer (score 1):

For my situation, I was sending a request properly as my view would expect, a `POST`. But the issue was on `http/s`. I had set a permanent redirect, from `http` to `https` on my app, and so sending a `POST` to the `http` version resulted in a `GET` somehow when the server was redirecting.

**TL;DR**

**HTTP instead of HTTPS**